# Filtering Out Blurry Images During Web Scraping with Selenium and XPath in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am currently working on a web scraping project in Python where I'm trying to scrape regular images from Reddit using Selenium and XPath. I have been successful in avoiding scraping of ads, videos, long images, and the like, but I've run into a problem when trying to exclude blurry images.

I have tried various XPaths to target and exclude these blurry images but have not been successful. My current solution isn't returning any errors, it's just not functioning as intended in this specific scenario. Unfortunately, I'm scraping unwanted blurry images which I would like to avoid.

Does anyone have suggestions or strategies for refining my XPath, or perhaps another approach to solve this problem? I'd appreciate any guidance on this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os

#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import urllib.request

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

reddit = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/Funnypics/']

time.sleep(10)  # Allow 10 seconds for the web page to open
scroll_pause_time = 2 # Pause time depending on laptop speed
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   #get the screen height of the web
media = set()

def redditscraper(subreddit):
    i = 1
    start_time = time.time()
    driver.get(subreddit)
    while True:
        if time.time() - start_time >= 60:
            break

        # scroll one screen height each time
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
        i += 1
        #pages_scrolled += 1
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    
        # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
        scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  

        images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, '_3Oa0THmZ3f5iZXAQ0hBJ0k ')] //img[not(ancestor::div[contains(@class, '_1NSbknF8ucHV2abfCZw2Z1 ') and not(ancestor::div[@data-testid='shreddit-player-wrapper']) and .//a[@data-adclicklocation='media'] and not(contains(@class, '_2_tDEnGMLxpM6uOa2kaDB3 ImageBox-image _1XWObl-3b9tPy64oaG6fax _3oBPn1sFwq76ZAxXgwRhhn'))  ])]")
        [media.add(img.get_attribute('src')) for img in images]

        # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
        if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
            break;

redditscraper(reddit[0])

# Set the directory where the GIF images will be saved
save_dir = "images"

# Create the directory if it does not exist
if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)

# Loop over the elements in the media set and download each GIF image
for i, url in enumerate(media):
    filename = os.path.join(save_dir, f"media{i}.gif")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

print(f"Total Number of Animated GIFs and Videos Stored is {len(media)}")
```

Comment: why not add more time for blurry images to load?

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary the images are permanently blurred because they contain either nudity, sexual, or violent content. Users must then click on them to unblur

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary Hey I think your solution might have worked. I love you

Comment: Please accept the answer if your issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images which are blurred contains "blur" in their src attribute
you can add below condition to your xpath

```
not(contains(@src, 'blur')
```

Complete Xpath

```
//div[(contains(@class, '_3Oa0THmZ3f5iZXAQ0hBJ0k'))] //img[not(contains(@src, 'blur')) and not(ancestor::div[contains(@class, '_1NSbknF8ucHV2abfCZw2Z1 ') and not(ancestor::div[@data-testid='shreddit-player-wrapper']) and .//a[@data-adclicklocation='media'] and not(contains(@class, '_2_tDEnGMLxpM6uOa2kaDB3 ImageBox-image _1XWObl-3b9tPy64oaG6fax _3oBPn1sFwq76ZAxXgwRhhn'))])]
```